# multiple wallets on same mobile device

Tags: wallet

Can I install and use different wallet apps on one mobile device?

The intention is to have:

- a hodl wallet and a daily use wallet
- And to compare GUI for preferred UE

Will the apps interfere with each other in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is no nothing preventing you to doing that as long as you use different private key, but usually your mobile wallet will generate an HD wallet for you so you wont have to deal with that problem.

Just be sure to use recognized mobile wallet like those here https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet?step=1

Also notice that some mobile wallet will offer you to have separate wallet inside their own software, like electrum

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use different wallet apps. But it’s better to keep hodl wallet separate from mobile device because of security reason.